# What is the subject in the following sentence here?

Tags: grammar, subjects

sorry for the vague title; I can't think of a clearer one.

**You are listening to *Friday Music World*. Coming up next is a song sure to give you inspiration to heal the world: "Heal the World" by Michael Jackson.**

See the second sentence in the paragraph above. And I can see two point of views:

1) The full sentence should be something like 'The song coming up next is~'. The subject is 'song', and 'coming' functions as adjective which modifies 'song'. Since the sentence is colloquial, 'The song' can be omitted because it's too obvious.

2) 'Coming' is a gerund, and it implies the meaning 'the next song' in this sentence. Therefore, 'coming' should be the subject here.

I think 1) is correct, but I am not sure about it. What is the right opinion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think it is a gerund in your example since it acts as a verb, not as a noun.

Comment: @Lawrence Yes, I think 'coming' doesn't act as a noun here. But what do you mean about 'it acts as a verb'? What did you mean by 'it', and isn't the verb 'is'?

Comment: In "Coming up" - the word "coming" is the 'action' of song. Compare "He was singing" (*singing* acts as a verb) with "His singing was loud" (*singing* acts as a noun). You can test this by trying to form a plural from the word. "The comings and goings of ..." - *coming* and *going* are both gerunds. " (*) Comings up next ..." doesn't work - it is a simple verb.

Comment: I think "*is*" is considered an [auxiliary verb](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/auxiliaryverb.htm) there; the main verb is "*coming*".

Comment: In the sentence "The song (which is) coming up next is..." , *coming* is an elided form of verb in the relative clause. In the sentence " Coming up next is a song...", *coming up next* is a gerund phrase functioning as the subject.